Are constraint relation between velocities and acceleration always identical?
My teacher told me these two points about constraint relations:-

Constraint relation between displacement and velocities of two bodies is identical.

Constraint relation between velocities and acceleration of bodies are identical when (a) motion starts from rest (b) velocities of the end point or blocks are along the length of string.


But how to prove these points that velocity and displacement will have an identical relation whereas acceleration will have an identical relation only under these conditions? I tried prove it but the books recommended by my teacher doesn't contain a problem where constraint relation between acceleration is asked and the bodies have velocity at an angle (other than 0 or 180).

Comment to the post (v1): Consider for clarity to include the mentioned constraint relations in formulas.

When you say "identical" do you mean in (1) that the velocity constraint is the derivative of the position constraint?  That isn't always true.

@MarianoG by identical it means if displacement of 2 bodies follow a relation $X_1=2X_2$ then velocities of these bodies will follow a relation $V_1=2V_2$

Ok so this is called an "integrable" velocity constraint.  The fancy word is "holonomic," although I doubt you will see that word used.   Not every velocity constraint is integrable to a position constraint, although many are, especially in introductory courses.  But if we are considering your specific case like $X_1 = 2 X_2$ then it is always true that $V_1 = 2 V_2 $ and $A_1 = 2 A_2$ by simple differentiation with respect to time.  Not sure but I suspect that your teacher is giving you some hints to help you solve a specific class of problems.  But they are not universally true.

Another higher-level way to ask your question is, "Is there a such thing as non-integrable acceleration constraints?"  I'm not sure.
